# PHP Upload Multiple Images to Directory - Fail

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

So I have this script which is working, it uploads images to the correct directory (that I create) and puts the images inside that directory & renames them, cool! However, The little display error text I've put in place is always printing EVERY single error. So for example I've got $j++ and with my errors there will be a max of $j = 4 and if $j = 4 then all the errors will print and you'd assume theres a problem and the images haven't been uploaded. However I selected 4 images and 3 of them uploaded but all the errors still displayed.

So my question is, why on earth and all the errors displaying and why are only 3 out of 4 images uploading? I want to be able to upload 30 images at 1 time...

**Code**

```
    //Image Upload Section

$j = 0; //Variable for indexing uploaded image 

    $target_path = $imagePath."/"; //Declaring Path for uploaded images
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) { //loop to get individual element from the array

        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png"); //Extensions which are allowed
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i])); //explode file name from dot(.) 
        $file_extension = end($ext); //store extensions in the variable

        $target_path = $target_path.md5(uniqid()).
        ".".$ext[count($ext) - 1]; //set the target path with a new name of image
        $j = $j + 1; //increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array       

        if (($_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000000) //Approx. 100000kb files can be uploaded.
            && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) { //if file moved to uploads folder
                echo $j.
                ').<span id="noerror">Image Uploaded Successfully!.</span><br/><br/>';
            } else { //if file was not moved.
                echo $j.
                ').<span id="error">Please Try Again!.</span><br/><br/>';
            }
        } else { //if file size and file type was incorrect.
            echo $j.
            ').<span id="error">***Invalid File Size or Type***</span><br/><br/>';
        }
    }

//End Image Upload Section
```

**Image**
[Image of all the errors (After 3 out of 4 Images Uploaded Successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hUxd.png)

**P.S**
On a side note, is there an easy way to loop through a directory and select all the images inside and then display them in HTML?

Comment: Are the image sizes within limits? `$_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000000`

Comment: Yeah, they are.

Comment: Try to echo `$_FILES["file"]["size"][$i] < 100000000` and `in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)` before actual upload, because certainly one of them is `false`